# Letting an `async for` fetch its next element while its body is `await`ing

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

In my codebase I have a function which returns an `AsyncIterator` over a resource. We can think of this resource as a linked list were I'm asking for each node asynchronously. I'd like to process each node using an async function, and to express that I can fetch the next element while I'm waiting for the current one to process.

To give an example, consider the following functions

```py
async def _get_next(prev: int) -> int:
        print(f"Fetching element {prev+1}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return prev + 1

async def fetch_elements(n: int) -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    curr = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        prev = curr
        curr = await _get_next(prev)
        print(f"Yielding element {curr}")
        yield curr

async def process_element(e: int) -> None:
    print(f"Pushing element {e}")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"Element {e} pushed")
```

I was under the impression that I could achieve this with `async for`, however this seems not to be the case, as if I run

```py
async for elem in fetch_elements(n):
    await push_element(elem)
```

I have to wait for `push_element` to finish before I can start fetching the next element. Is there a simple way to achieve this, or do I have to do away with the `AsyncIterator`?

Comment: Don't await the push. If you await, you will be stuck there.

Comment: But if I don't await the `push_element`, then I'll have to wait until I fetch all the elements, when I could be processing the ones I had already received in the meantime. I also can't `await asyncio.gather(*(elem async for elem in fetch_elements(n)))` since `asyncio.gather` doesn't work with `AsyncIterable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
async def fetch_elements(n: int):
    curr = 0
    for _ in range(n - 1):
        task = asyncio.create_task(_get_next(curr))
        yield curr
        curr = await task
    yield curr
```

You want to start a separate task to fetch the next element before returning the current one.  But on the last iteration of the loop, you have to be careful *not* to fetch the next element.

---

Updated to handle the last iteration specially.